# IO Error [Errno 2]

Tags: python, pdf, random, printing, pypdf

So I'm a beginning programmer, and python is my first language. I'm trying to write a script that will open a random PDF from a directory and select a random page from that PDF to read. When I run my script I get the error code IO ERROR: [Errno 2] and then displays the title of the selected PDF. How can I fix this? I am using the pyPdf module. Are there any other problems in the code you can see?

```
    import os, random, pyPdf

    from pyPdf import PdfFileReader

    b = random.choice(os.listdir("/home/illtic/PDF"))

    pdf_toread = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open(b, 'r'))

    last_page = pdf_toread.getNumPages() - 1

    page_one = pdf_toread.getPage(random.randint(0, last_page))

    print " %d " % page_one
```

Comment: are you using pyPDF or pyPDF2?

Answer (score 4):

what value does `b` have? I am pretty sure that it is just the filename without the path. Try adding the path in front of the filename and it should be ok.

```
pdf_toread = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open('/home/illtic/PDF/' + b, 'r'))
```

Comment: errno 2 is "no such file or directory" which fits with this answer solving the problem

Comment: Same thing.

**Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "RandomPDF.py", line 6, in <module>

    pdf_toread = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open('home/illtic/PDF' + b, 'r'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

 'home/illtic/PDFSpinoza, Benedict de - The Ethics 2. Of the Nature and Origin of the Mind.pdf'**

Comment: I think you're missing a trailing slash after `/PDF` now

Comment: Thanks guys, it was the path and forward slash. Now my only dilemma is how do I display the contents in text format?

**{'/Parent': IndirectObject(80, 0), '/Contents': IndirectObject(48, 0), '/Resources': IndirectObject(47, 0), '/Rotate': 0, '/CropBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/MediaBox': [0, 0, 612, 792], '/Type': '/Page'}**